# Why 'this' points to window inside a function when apply() or call() is being called?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm reading Nicholas Z.Zakas' Professional JavaScript for web developer 3rd edition and inside the Reference types chapter I got a bit confused at the function type part.

```
function sum(num1, num2){
return num1 + num2;
}

function callSum1(num1, num2){
return sum.apply(this, arguments);
}

alert(callSum1(10,10)); //20
```

### He says:

*"In this example, `callSum1()` executes the `sum()` method, passing in `this` as the `this` value **(which is equal to `window` because it's being called in the global scope)** and also passing in the `arguments` object."*

I understand what he says, but I don't understand the why. `This` supposed to point to the function doesn't it? Now I'm confused that it's pointing to the **window** because it's being called in the global scope ..

*Can someone be kind to explain it to me? :)*

I'm not sure if I will or I have to use this technique later, but I want to make sure I understand it, especially the this part. More details about `this` and its usage will come in the OOP section, but it's now an interesting question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, I'm surprised to see that example (I haven't read Zakas' book). I've heard good things about Zakas' book, but this example seems almost *designed* to confuse. I assume that's because it's out of context. The point of the comment is: Don't worry if you're confused by this, it's a bit confusing. :-)

Comment: He explained a bit more detailed in the following page, but I needed your explanations as well. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on how you call a function.

If you call a function using `call` or `apply` then the value of `this` will be the first argument to that function.

Here you have `sum.apply(this, arguments);` so it will pass the current value through. As usual, that value is determined by how you call the function.

Since you call `callSum1(10,10)` with no context, `this` will be `window`.

(If you were in strict mode, it would be `undefined`. If you weren't in a browser, it would be whatever the default object of the JS environment you were using was).

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm reading now, I didn't try it in a browser. Is it recommended to write my codes in strict mode?

Comment: Strict mode enforces some coding practises that can help you avoid some bugs. It is generally recommended (so long as you test in a browser that supports it!)

Comment: Got it, thanks! So actually it's more sensitive for things and throws more errors and I can get more headache. :D But in the end I'll have a good habit how to write proper JS codes. I'll consider this and study the strict mode deeper. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
alert(callSum1(10,10)); //20
```

...you're calling `callSum` without doing anything to set `this` during the call, and so `this` is defaulted to the global object (`window`, on browsers). (In loose mode; in strict mode, `this` would have been `undefined`.)

Since you're then using `apply` and passing that same `this` into it:

```
return sum.apply(this, arguments);
```

...naturally the global object is also used when calling `sum`.

> I understand what he says, but I don't understand the why. This supposed to point to the function doesn't it?

No, `this` almost never refers to functions. (It can, of course, it just very rarely does.)

> Now I'm confused that it's pointing to the window because it's being called in the global scope ..

It's not because it's being called in the global scope; it would be the same if it were being called from inside a function. What matters isn't *where* the call occurs, but *how*. Any time you call a function without doing anything to set `this`, in loose mode, `this` during the function call will be the global object. It doesn't have to be at global scope; what matters is how you call the function.

The rule is actually a lot simpler than people make it out to be: If you call a function without doing anything to set `this`, during the call, `this` will be the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode). Here are the things you can do to set `this` during a function call:

1. Call the function as part of an expression getting the function from a property on an object. For example, `foo.bar();` retrieves a reference to the function from the `bar` property on `foo`, then calls `bar`. Because we did it that way, during the call to `bar`, `this` refers to `foo`.
2. Call the function using `.call` or `.apply`; `this` will be what you pass in the first argument. (In loose mode, if you pass `undefined`, `null`, or a non-object in the first argument, during the call `this` will be the global object. In strict mode, it'll be what you pass.)
3. Call a *bound* function. That's a function created via `Function#bind` (an ES5 feature). Bound functions have `this` "baked into" them.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: I think I got confused because he said in the book that in ES the functions are actually objects and I know that with 'this' I can referr to an object. But I'll read toward and I'll see what he have to say in the OOP section about 'this'. :)

Comment: @ThePianist: And it's true: Functions are objects in JavaScript, and `this` refers to objects (in loose mode; in strict mode `this` can be anything). But just about the only time `this` refers to a function object is when you're adding features to `Function.prototype`, which is fairly advanced stuff. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Under the Window object part ~20 pages later, I'm reading this: ***"As mentioned previously, the `this` value is equivalent to the Global object when a function is executed with no explicit `this` value specified (either by being an object method or via `call()`/`apply()`)."*** :)

Maybe I didn't get it before, but now it's clear with his words as well. By the way, the book is awesome! Now with Math object I can understand much more the apply() method, too.

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
```